# Generating multiple random numbers in a loop in C

Tags: c

This program is supposed to run a simulation to see if a number the user entered is less than three randomly generated numbers. All the numbers range from 0 to 1. The user specifies the number of trials for the simulation to run and then the program tells the user the number of times all three numbers were less than theirs and the number of times it wasn't. The problem is every time i run the program i always get 1 pass or 1 fail regardless of how many trials it was supposed to run. I think this is because i am only generating one set of random numbers instead of however many specified but i am not sure how to fix this.

here is the code -

```
int main()
{
int seed, trials, pass1, fail1, i, j, k;
float reli;

printf("Enter individual component reliability:\n");
scanf("%f", &reli);

printf("Enter number of trials:\n");
scanf("%u", &trials);



srand(time(NULL));
float rndm1 = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
float rndm2 = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
float rndm3 = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

while( k <= trials ); {
    pass1 = 0;
    fail1 = 0;
    if (rndm1 <= reli && rndm2 <= reli && rndm3 <= reli){
        pass1 = pass1 + 1;
    }
    else { 
    fail1 = fail1 + 1;  
}

k++;
}
printf("# of passes = %d, #of failures = %d", pass1, fail1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `scanf("%u", &trials);` --> `scanf("%d", &trials);`

Comment: When you define a local non-static variable (like for example your variable `k`) it will not automatically be initialized. It will have an *indeterminate* value. Using it without initialization might lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You need to move the rndm1, rndm2, rnd3 and calls to rand() inside the while loop. You need to generate new random numbers for every trial ( I am guessing this).

Comment: Yes, because you re-assign `pass1` and `fail1` every iteration.

Comment: Also, your `main` function declaration is non-standard, it should be `int main(void)` if you don't use any arguments. In C using nothing in the argument list (like e.g. `void function()`) is different from declaring a function explicitly with a `void` argument (like `void function(void)`). The first (empty list) declares a function with an unknown number of arguments of unknown type. The second (with `void` argument) declares a function taking no arguments.

Comment: `while( k <= trials );` What's with the semi-colon? I'm voting to close for that...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude WRT your first comment -- No, it *will* cause undefined behavior. That's definitely true. Whether or not it causes *errors* is not guaranteed and, indeed, not defined. :)

Answer (score 2):

4 things I think are the problem:

As Ajay said: 
You just generate 1 set of numbers and it seems you want to get a different set everytime. So you should move it into the loop.

Then you reset your pass and fail values every time you go through the loop. So it starts with `0` again every time. You might want to move the declaration out of the loop.

3rd thing is you don't have a loop. `while( k <= trials );` means that there is nothing to be done. Because the end of the loop is at the `;`. You have to remove it.

Then again as StoryTeller mentioned you have to initialize the variables before you use them. It is just pure luck that you didn't run into an infinite loop so do `k=0;` before you use `k`

```
int main()
{
int seed, trials, pass1, fail1, i, j, k;
float reli;
float rndm1;
float rndm2;
float rndm3;

printf("Enter individual component reliability:\n");
scanf("%f", &reli);

printf("Enter number of trials:\n");
scanf("%u", &trials);



srand(time(NULL));
pass1 = 0;
fail1 = 0;
k = 0;

while( k < trials )
{
    rndm1 = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX; //one cast is enough but casting both is not wrong and if you use float cast to float
    rndm2 = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    rndm3 = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX; 

    if (rndm1 <= reli && rndm2 <= reli && rndm3 <= reli)
    {
        pass1 = pass1 + 1;
    }
    else 
    { 
        fail1 = fail1 + 1;  
    }
    k++;
}
printf("# of passes = %d, #of failures = %d", pass1, fail1);
}
```